# Intellij maven can't find artifact and relative path error

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Good day. I have 2 `module`'s in my project.None of those `module`'s seem to find parent `artifact` and are complaining about the `relative path` pointer.

**Error #1**

> Could not find artifact com.petclinic:pet-clinic:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

**Error #2**

> 'parent.relativePath' of POM
> com.petclinic:pet-clinic-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/name/Desktop/Java
> Projects/pet-clinic/pet-clinic-web/pom.xml) points at
> com.petclinic:petclinic instead of com.petclinic:pet-clinic, please
> verify your project structure

**Root pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.petclinic</groupId>

    <artifactId>petclinic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>petclinic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>


    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>pet-clinic-web</module>
        <module>pet-clinic-data</module>
    </modules>
<!--    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>-->
<!--    <artifactId>pet-clinic</artifactId>-->
<!--    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
<!--    <name>pet-clinic</name>-->
<!--    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>-->
<!--    <properties>-->
<!--        <java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
<!--    </properties>-->
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Child pom #1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.petclinic</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>

    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>


    </properties>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is exactly what the error message describes: in the child pom you specify the `<parent>` as `<artifactId>pet-clinic</artifactId>`, but the actual parent specifies in its pom.xml `<artifactId>petclinic</artifactId>`. Just keep the dash consistent between the artifact ids!

Comment: What is the result of the Maven build from the command line? `mvn compile`?